# Count distinct values in MySQL without folding NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, count, null, aggregate-functions

I have table `a` with two fields: `id` (PK) and `f`.

Consider following records:

```
id | f
1  | NULL
2  | 'foo'
3  | 'bar'
4  | NULL
5  | 'foo'
6  | 'baz'
```

I want to retrieve and count all the records having distinct `f` values including every record `WHERE f IS NULL`. Given this criteria, the query should return every record except #5, because the same value is already included in the set, and the total count would be 5.

The query I'm using to retrieve all records looks like this:

`SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM a a2 WHERE a2.f = a.f AND a.id < a2.id) THEN 1 END AS not_distinct FROM a HAVING not_distinct IS NULL`

If this query could be improved, I'd welcome any feedback. Anyway, the main problem is counting. Obviously adding a `COUNT(*)` will not help here and I'm totally lost how to count the records after the filtering.

Comment: Can you please provide sample data you wish to get as o/p?

Comment: @AjithSasidharan: The question is already clear on that: `the query should return every record except #5, because the same value is already included in the set, and the total count would be 5.`

Comment: Yes go the requirement now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` in a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM   a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a a2 WHERE a2.f = a.f AND a2.id < a.id);
```

This way you can also get actual rows - if you need more than the bare count:

```
SELECT *
FROM   a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a a2 WHERE a2.f = a.f AND a2.id < a.id)
```

The `=` operator makes sure that *all* rows with `f IS NULL` are included. You had that in your query already.

[-> sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b64ee/13)

Neither of these would work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT f FROM a;

SELECT * FROM a GROUP BY f;
```

.. because both would also fold `NULL` values, and you want

> every record WHERE f IS NULL.

Comment: This solution seems so obvious I wonder why I haven't figured it out myself. Thanks a lot, works beautifully.

Comment: That's the thing with solutions: most seem so obvious once you *have* them. :)

Answer (score 16):

There's a pretty simple approach that might work for you:

```
select count(distinct ifnull(f, id))
from a
```

Note that this query assumes that f values are never id values, and based on sample data and experience this is reasonable.

#### Edited:

I thought about it and there's an even *simpler* approach:

```
select count(distinct f) + sum(f is null) from a;
```

which you can see [running on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b64ee/15)

This works because `distinct` throws away nulls, and `sum(condition)` counts the number of times condition is true because in mysql true is `1` and false is `0`.

Comment: Although your solution generally is better performance-wise, I chose Erwin's answer since it suits my needs better in current situation. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @package See edited answer for another pretty simple approach that will perform well too, but is less "smarty pants". (btw, the answer you selected will always suck performance wise).

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE comments SET view =     
                              (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT browser, ip, ifnull(user_id, 0)) 
                              FROM counters WHERE item_type=comments.item_type )
    WHERE id=1
```